# How to know when GET request is finished with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt

How do you know when QNetworkAcessManager GET request is finished? Is there a signal it emits or a way to busy wait until the request is finished? I currently have a QTimer set for 300ms for waiting.

```
#include <QApplication>

Downloader::Downloader(QApplication *app)  {
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(app);
}

void Downloader::TestConnection(QString theUrl) const {

    auto status = connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Downloader::ReplyFinished);
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(theUrl)));
}

void Downloader::ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {

    theNetworkData = reply->readAll();
}

QString Downloader::getNetworkData() {

    return theNetworkData;
}
```

And in the main file:

```
 auto downloaderObject = new Downloader(qApp);
    downloaderObject->TestConnection("http://theurl");

    // Delay 300ms for network reply
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(300, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();

    networkAnswer = downloaderObject->getNetworkData();
```

Comment: `QNetworkAccessManager::get` returns a `QNetworkReply` which has method `isFinished`

Comment: I found this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished but you must be talking about this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkreply.html#isFinished interesting.

Comment: I don't see a way to do it while the QNetworkAccessManager is encapsulated in a class.

Answer (score 2):

The get request will send the "Finished" signal, which you have already hooked into with the line:

```
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Downloader::ReplyFinished);
```

The bit that confused me was the part about waiting with a timer...  Then it clicked, your basically wanting to initiate a GET, set a delay and "hope" that the GET finishes before the delay expires.

Most apps I have written use the GET within a GUI of some sort, and therefore it is all signal driven and no need to wait as such.  But on the basis that you are wanting to "delay" whilst allowing the Finished signal to be emitted, the following code will do that...

I knocked it together in about 15 minutes so it's not pretty, but it does what you were asking (I think!).

Downloader.h

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

#include <QObject>

class QNetworkConfiguration;
class QNetworkAccessManager;
class QNetworkConfigurationManager;
class QNetworkReply;
class QNetworkSession;

class Downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Downloader(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Downloader();
    bool open_network_connection();
    bool is_finished();
    void TestConnection(QString) const;
    QString getNetworkData();

private slots:
    void ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);

signals:

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_network_manager;
    QNetworkReply* m_reply;
    QNetworkConfigurationManager *m_configuration_manager;
    QNetworkSession *m_session;

    QString theNetworkData;

    bool can_start_iap;
    bool finished;
};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

Downloader.cpp

```
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkSession>

#include "downloader.h"

Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
    , m_network_manager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
    , m_configuration_manager(new QNetworkConfigurationManager(this))
{
    finished = false;
    QObject::connect(m_network_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Downloader::ReplyFinished);
}

Downloader::~Downloader() {
    delete m_network_manager;
    delete m_configuration_manager;
    delete m_session;
}

bool Downloader::open_network_connection() {
    can_start_iap = (m_configuration_manager->capabilities() &
                                QNetworkConfigurationManager::CanStartAndStopInterfaces);
    QNetworkConfiguration m_configuration = m_configuration_manager->defaultConfiguration();

    if(!m_configuration.isValid() || (!can_start_iap && m_configuration.state() != QNetworkConfiguration::Active)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        finished = false;
        m_session = new QNetworkSession(m_configuration);
        m_session->open();
        return m_session->waitForOpened(-1);
    }
}

void Downloader::TestConnection(QString theUrl) const {
    m_network_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(theUrl)));
}

void Downloader::ReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        theNetworkData = QString(reply->readAll());
    }
    else {
        theNetworkData = QString("Network Error");
    }
    finished = true;
}

QString Downloader::getNetworkData() {
    return theNetworkData;
}

bool Downloader::is_finished() {    
    return finished;
}
```

And Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTime>

#include "downloader.h"

void delay( int millisecondsToWait );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Downloader *downloaderObject = new Downloader(nullptr);
    if (downloaderObject->open_network_connection()) {
        downloaderObject->TestConnection("<Enter a valid URL here>");

        while(!downloaderObject->is_finished()) {
            delay(1000);
        }
        qDebug() << downloaderObject->getNetworkData();

    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Error";
    }

    delete downloaderObject;

    return a.exec();
}

void delay( int millisecondsToWait )
{
    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs( millisecondsToWait );
    while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100 );
    }
}
```

the .pro file (ubuntu 20.04 based)

```
QT       += core gui
QT += network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        downloader.cpp \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    downloader.h
```

Like I say, this was knocked together pretty quick, there could be lots more error checking, validation, etc and it's not necessarily how I would write it at work but it shows what I think you were trying to achieve.

Compiles and runs on QT Creator 9.0.2, QT 5.12.8

Comment: Interesting, but it seems QNetworkConfigurationManager was deprecated for QT6: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/network-changes-qt6.html heh.

Answer (score 1):

Both QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply have finished signals:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkreply.html#finished

And I see you already used it.

You can find an example here: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils/blob/master/lqtutils_net.cpp#L99. That class downloads a file and emits a signal when done, pretty similar to what you need.